# Trouble with Python Inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, object

The code that I'm acttualy having the problem with is very long, so I made an example that displays my problem.

I have two classes that inherit from a base-class (**BaseClass**). Both of these classes add some elements to **self.Dict**. However, they seem to cross contaminate elements. I was expecting **c0.Dict** to return **{'class0': 0}** and **c1.Dict** to return **{'class1': 1}**. However they both return **{'class0': 0, 'class1': 1}**. Why do they cross contaminate?

```
class BaseClass :
    def __init__ (self, _dict={}) :
        self.Dict = _dict

class Class0 (BaseClass) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.Dict['class0'] = 0

class Class1 (BaseClass) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        BaseClass.__init__(self)
        self.Dict['class1'] = 1

c0 = Class0()
c1 = Class1()

print c0.Dict
print c1.Dict
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You hit a python gotcha : mutable default arguments.

http://blog.objectmentor.com/articles/2008/05/22/pythons-mutable-default-problem

```
class BaseClass :
    def __init__ (self, _dict=None) :
        self.Dict = _dict or {}
```

Comment: LOL, I was not expecting that. I was practically pulling my hair out trying to figure out where some strange side effects were coming from in my program. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the fix you posted fixes the problem. Thanks for the quick reply too.

Comment: yeah, I felt like you did when I hit that one, ie WTF ? (a few hours later) damn, ok...